# Am I awaiting incorrectly or is there another issue?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm new to React, but not development. I'm in my first independent project since training.  I'm using redux.

I've created a simple list app that requires login.  Login is working. BUT. If I login, then refresh, the redux store loses everything. So I'm setting the user's token in session storage to overcome this issue, so that I can get the user's data from the database with the token if they refresh.

The problem seems to be that when I use axios to get the user's data from the database based on the token, it's not awaiting properly and then continues to process the page and bombs because it doesn't have the user_id yet.  It's bombing because I'm trying to access user_id from this.props.auth.userId.user_id and it doesn't have it for some reason.

App.js

```
import React  from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ListItemCreate from './listitems/listItemCreate';
import ListItemEdit from './listitems/listItemEdit';
import ListItemDelete from './listitems/listItemDelete';
import ListItemList from './listitems/listItemList';
import ListItemShow from './listitems/listItemShow';
import Header from './Header';
import history from '../history';
import Login from './Login/Login';
import Register from './Login/Register';
import { signInWithToken } from '../actions';

const setToken = (userToken) => {
     sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(userToken));
 }
const getToken = () => {
    //sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
    const tokenString = sessionStorage.getItem('token');

    if(tokenString){
    const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
    
    console.log('The Token for you, madam: ' +userToken.token);
    return userToken?.token;
    }
    return null;
} 

class App extends React.Component {
    //state = { isSignedIn: null };

    render(){
        const isSignedIn = this.props.auth.isSignedIn;
        const curToken = getToken();
        console.log('curToken: '+curToken);
        if(curToken && !isSignedIn){
            console.log('need signInWithToken');
            this.props.signInWithToken(curToken);
        }

        if(isSignedIn){
            console.log('because isSignedIn is TRUE');
            //console.log(this.props.auth);
            if(!curToken){setToken({ 'token': this.props.auth.userId.token });}

            const user_id = this.props.auth.userId.user_id;
            const email = this.props.auth.userId.email;
            const token = this.props.auth.userId.token;
            console.log('isSignedId:' + isSignedIn);
            console.log('user_id:'+user_id);
            console.log('email:' + email);
            console.log('token:' + token);
            console.log('getting isSigned in');
            if (isSignedIn) {
                console.log('it has VALUE');
                console.log(this.props.isSignedIn);
            } else {
                console.log('no isSignedIn');
            }
        }
        if(curToken){console.log('curToken:' + curToken);}
    //const token = getToken();
    //console.log();
        if(isSignedIn || curToken){
            console.log('i HAVE a token');
            return(
                <div className="ui container">
                    <Router history={history}>
                        <div>
                            <Header />
                            <Switch>
                            <Route path="/" exact component={ListItemList} />
                            <Route path="/listitems/new" exact component={ListItemCreate} />
                            <Route path="/listitems/edit/:list_item_id" exact component={ListItemEdit} />
                            <Route path="/listitems/delete/:list_item_id" exact component={ListItemDelete} />
                            <Route path="/listitems/:list_item_id" exact component={ListItemShow} />
                            </Switch>
                        </div>
                    </Router>
                </div>
            );
        }else{

            console.log('NO token');
            return(
                <div className="ui container">
                    <Router history={history}>
                        <div>
                            <Header />
                            <Switch>
                            <Route path="/" exact component={Login} setToken={setToken} />
                            <Route path="/register" exact component={Register} setToken={setToken}  />
                            
                            </Switch>
                        </div>
                    </Router>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { auth: state.auth };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { signInWithToken })(App);
```

From the action creator (but not the whole file):

```
export const signInWithToken = (token) => async (dispatch) => {
    console.log('signInWithToken');
    
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('grant_type', 'signinwithtoken');
    data.append('token', token);

    const response = await user.post(`theurl/token`, data)
    .then(response => {
        console.log('and the response is'); // << It's showing me this in the console just AFTER the error where it needs to access the user_id
        console.log(response.data);
        
        dispatch({ type: SIGN_IN_WITH_TOKEN, payload: response.data });
        history.push('/');
        return {
            type: SIGN_IN_WITH_TOKEN,
            payload: response.data
        };
    });

};
```

The Reducer:

```
import { SIGN_IN, SIGN_OUT, LOGIN, REGISTER, SIGN_IN_WITH_TOKEN } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    isSignedIn: null,
    userId: null
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case REGISTER:
            return { ...state, isSignedIn: true, userId: action.payload };
        case LOGIN:
            return { ...state, isSignedIn: true, userId: action.payload };
        case SIGN_IN:
            return { ...state, isSignedIn: true, userId: action.payload };
        case SIGN_OUT:
            return { ...state, isSignedIn: false, userId: null };
        case SIGN_IN_WITH_TOKEN:
            return { ...state, isSignedIn: true, userId: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Here is ListItemList that is rendered as long as there's a user_id:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { fetchListItems, markListItemCompleted } from '../../actions';
import MultiSort from '../MultiSort';

class ListItemList extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('in ListItemList');
        console.log(this.props);
        const id = this.props.currentUserId;
        if(id){
            this.props.fetchListItems(id);
        }else{
            
        }
        
    }

    markCompleted(listItem){
        console.log('in markCompleted');
        console.log(listItem);
        // you need to pass the data, but completion datetime needs to be set

        let currentdate = new Date(); 
        let datetime = currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                + currentdate.getFullYear() + " "  
                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                + currentdate.getSeconds();

        console.log(datetime);        
        this.props.markListItemCompleted(listItem.list_item_id);
        

    }

    renderAdmin(listItem){
       // if(listItem.userId === this.props.currentUserId){
            return (
                <div className="right floated content">
                    <button className="ui button secondary" onClick={() => this.markCompleted(listItem)} >Mark {listItem.completion_label}</button>
                    <Link to={`/listItems/edit/${listItem.list_item_id}`} className="ui button primary">Edit</Link>
                    <Link to={`/listItems/delete/${listItem.list_item_id}`} className="ui button negative">Delete</Link>
                </div>
            );
        //}
    }

    formatCompletedDT(dt = null){
        if(dt === "0000-00-00 00:00:00"){return "Never";}
        let date = new Date(dt);
        let day = date.getDate();
        let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        let year = date.getFullYear();
        let hour = date.getHours();
        let minute = date.getMinutes();
        let second = date.getSeconds();

        return month + '/' + day + '/' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;
    }


    renderList(){
        const noNulls = this.props.listItems.map(listItem => {
            if(!listItem.last_completed_dt){
                listItem.last_completed_dt = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
            }
            return listItem;
        });

        const sortedList = MultiSort(noNulls, { last_completed_dt: 'asc', list_item: 'asc'});
         
        return sortedList.map(listItem => {
            const lastCompleted = this.formatCompletedDT(listItem.last_completed_dt);

           // if(listItem.userId === this.props.currentUserId){
                return (
                    <div className="item" key={listItem.list_item_id}>
                        {this.renderAdmin(listItem)}
                        <i className="large middle aligned icon check circle" />
                        <div className="content">
                            <Link to={`/listItems/${listItem.list_item_id}`} className="header">
                                {listItem.list_item}
                            </Link>
                            <div className="description" style={{ color: 'grey', fontSize: '9pt' }} >Last {listItem.completion_label}: {lastCompleted}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
           // }   
        });
    }
    renderCreateButton(){
        //if(this.props.isSignedIn){
            return(
                <div style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>
                    <Link to="/listItems/new" className="ui button primary">
                        Create List Item
                    </Link>
                </div>
            );
        //}
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>List Items</h2>
                <div className="ui celled list">{this.renderList()}</div>
                {this.renderCreateButton()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { 
        listItems: Object.values(state.listItems),
        currentUserData: state.auth.userId,
        isSignedIn: state.auth.isSignedIn,
        auth: state.auth
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchListItems, markListItemCompleted })(ListItemList);
```

And the action creator for ListItemList:

```
export const fetchListItems = (userId) => async dispatch => {
    const response = await listItems.get(`/listItemsMaintenance?user_id=${userId}`);

    dispatch({ type: FETCH_LIST_ITEMS, payload: response.data });
};
```

I trust that if my plan is horrendously flawed, you'll tell me.

Comment: You should in general not mix `await` and `.then()`

Comment: @mousetail Thanks for the tip!  I was trying to see if that would fix my issue.  It did not.

Comment: Your problem is this if statement `if(isSignedIn || curToken){` when it renders with token but not yet signed in then you try to render as if you already have the user information. Implement setting a loading value in your reducer and set it to true in your `signInWithToken` action before doing async and set it to false when the promise is done (fail or success).

Comment: FYI it's not inherently an error to mix syntaxes but it makes it harder to read and understand so I agree that you should avoid it.  I haven't checked your whole code but @HMR is usually right :)

Comment: @HMR If you post this as an answer, I'll award it.  Very helpful! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this if statement: `if(isSignedIn || curToken){` when it renders with token but not yet signed in then you try to render as if you already have the user information. Implement setting a loading value in your reducer and set it to true in your `signInWithToken` action before doing async and set it to false when the promise is done (fail or success).